# My Minecraft optifine cape wont appear

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-optifine

I don't know if this is the right place to ask but just about an hour and a half ago I donated to optifine to get a Minecraft cape and when I join Minecraft both single player and multiplayer the cape simply will not appear on my back. I even restarted the game and asked people on the hypixel server if they could see my cape and they all said no. I've been searching all over the internet for help and the things I found didn't work, like toggling capes on in the video settings. one website said I should change my optifine cape and it might work but when I DO try to change my cape on the optifine website it says that the password is invalid even though I know with 100% certainty that the password is correct, I even went to my email and found the email receipt I got for the payment going through and I checked my bank account and saw that the money had come out so I definitely paid for it. the optifine website doesn't specify whether it needs my Minecraft password or my email password either btw and I tried both passwords and it was STILL invalid.

Comment: DO NOT ENTER YOUR MINECRAFT PASSWORD OR YOUR MAIL ACCOUNT PASSWORD ON ANY OTHER WEBSITE THAN MINECRAFT.NET, MOJANG.COM, THE LAUNCHER OR YOUR MAIL WEBSITE/PROGRAM! Now you've sent them your password, so they can access your accounts! You should immediately change your Minecraft password and your mail password!

Answer (score 2):

Optifine capes can only be seen with the Optifine version of Minecraft (or the Forge version with Optifine loaded), because it's not an official cape by Mojang. It's not saved on your account, but instead the Optifine version of Minecraft checks on Optifine's servers for a cape.
So of course other players can't see your cape and you can't either, unless they or you play with Optifine.

Also maybe it takes a little while for them to process your donation. Try again in the next few days (maybe it requires manual action and the people don't work on the weekend) and if it's still not there then, contact them and ask if it's finished processing.

Comment: I checked the website in the FAQ section and it said the cape should appear straight away

Comment: and yes I've already launched the game with optifine I'm not playing vanilla.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have paid a certain amount of money to get the cape. Maybe you bought it from a fake site. If not, you probably didn't say that you wanted a cape. Always make sure it the real site you're on or you might end up wasting money.

Comment: It was definitely the official site, I never buy something from a website unless I know that its the official site for sure. it was 5 days ago I donated and I know I donated enough because I went on the cape section of the website and it said to type my username to change my cape and also said if you don't yet have a cape than use the link to donate and I did and it even got me to choose a cape (I used a custom cape). The money came out of my account and I got an email saying that it went through.

Answer (score 0):

Just people have OptiFine cape can see OptiFine's cape of others people.

Cape can just be obtain by going to MineCon. OptiFine can't change your personnals skins details, just Mojang can be that.

I hope that my answer helped you !   :-)

Comment: That's incorrect, I could see other peoples capes even when I hadn't even donated, I could see my friends cape when playing on my realm. also, MineCon is no longer an actual convention, it is a livestream as of 2017 so the "go to MineCon to get a proper cape" isn't a thing anymore because they don't do MineCon capes anymore sadly.

Answer (score 0):

After waiting about a week I finally have my optifine activated after I got a new email saying the cape could be activated now. thanks for the help.

Comment: This question is still marked as unanswered. Can you accept this answer by clicking the check mark to the left just to set it to "answered" and make it easier for people who are having the same problem to find your solution (even if you only had to wait for a delayed email)?